# How to create the "show in mail" link in Apple Calendar?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, calendar

I'm wondering how can I make the "show in mail" link as seen in the photo below. Currently if i click a date in an email it will automatically create the link in the Calendar app. Can I do it manually for emails that don't contain dates?

How can I link associate a mail with an event in Calendar ?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can

- Drag & drop a mail into the Calendar window to create a new entry with a link to the mail
- Open an existing event in Calendar and drag&drop a mail into the "Notes, URL or attachments" field

PS: This may work for iCloud calenders only

Comment: Your first bulletpoint works for me, but the second one does not, although it creates a link that looks the same as the photo i shared when i drag and drop the email. It opens the web-browser when i click on it instead of opening the mail client? also, how would i do this on IOS?

Comment: @MohammadAli You are dragging from Apple Mail into Calendar, right? Did you change the handling of mailto: links maybe?

Comment: So dragging the mail into a calendar day works fine for me and has the desired result, but dragging an email into an already created calandar events url area instead of saying “show in mail” it will display the title of the email and will open in the web browser when clicked

Comment: @MohammadAli Which version of macOS are you using?

Comment: The latest one, I have it set to auto update

Comment: neither of these two methods works for me (Big Sur on M1). Drag and Drop into the calendar app creates the event but without any link. And dragging into the Notes/Attachment field doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Christoph I just tried on Big Sur/M1, drag&drop still works here. Are you dragging from the standard Mail application?

Comment: Yes, I'm dragging from the Apple Mail app to the Apple Calendar app. Event created but no link.

Comment: @Christoph Strange. There seems to be at least one other person who sees the same. Wonder what kind of setting is at work here.

Comment: It appears that the backlink is only created if your calendar is on iCloud but not Exchange or Gmail...